# Como faço para imprimir os resultados das condições dentro da index php?

Tags: php, html

**Estou fazendo desse modo e quando é para imprimir o resultado(Após o usuário selecionar o submit em outra index), não aparece nada. Fica em branco.**
**ONDE RECEBE OS DADOS VIA POST DO FORMULÁRIO DO TIPO RÁDIO E ESTABELECE AS CONDIÇÕES:**

```
<?php
            // Recebendo as respostas do Usuário
            $perfil = $_POST["pergunta1"];
            $condicao = $_POST["pergunta2"];
            //Iniciando as variáveis
            $cpu = "cpu";
            $rom = "rom";
            $ram = "ram";
            


            // Primeiro caso: Perfil de uso - Dia a dia
            if ($perfil == "diadia" && $condicao == "economico") {
                $cpu = "Intel Celeron";
                $rom = "HDD 300GB";
                $ram = "2GB DDR3";

            } elseif ($perfil == "diaadia" && $condicao == "normal") {
                $cpu = "Intel Core i3";
                $rom = "HDD 500GB";
                $ram = "4GB DDR3";

            }
            // Segundo caso: Perfil de uso - Trabalho
            elseif ($perfil == "trabalho" && $condicao == "economico") {
                $cpu = "Intel Core i3";
                $rom = "HDD 500GB";
                $ram = "4GB DDR3";
            
            } elseif ($perfil == "trabalho" && $condicao == "normal") {
                $cpu = "Intel Core i5";
                $rom = "HDD 1TB";
                $ram = "8GB DDR3";  
                $video = "2GB";
            }
            // Terceiro caso: Perfil de uso - Edição
            elseif ($perfil == "edicao" && $condicao == "economico") {
                $cpu = "Intel Core i5";
                $rom = "HDD 1TB";
                $ram = "8GB DDR3";
                $video = "2GB";
            } elseif ($perfil == "edicao" && $condicao == "normal") {
                $cpu = "Intel Core i7";
                $rom = "HDD 1TB";
                $ram = "12GB DDR3";
                $video = "4GB";
            };?>
```

**ONDE SERÁ MOSTRADO AO USUÁRIO AS CONFIGURAÇÕES DE ACORDO COM AS CONDIÇÕES:**

```
 <section class="page-section bg-primary text-white mb-0">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="divider-custom divider-light">
            <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
            <div class="divider-custom-icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
            <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- About Section Content-->
        <div class="row">
             <?php
                  
            
            echo "Processador: $cpu " . "<br>";
            echo "Armazenamento: $rom " . "<br>";
            echo "Memoria RAM: $ram "  . "<br>";
            if ($perfil = "edicao" && $condicao = "economico"){
                echo "Placa de video dedicada: $video" . "<br>";

            } elseif ($perfil = "edicao" && $condicao = "normal"){
                echo "Placa de video dedicada: $video " . "<br>";
            };
             
            
            
            ?>

            
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Verifique se o código abaixo atende. Note que os ifs foram drasticamente reduzidos, e que se você quiser acrescentar novos perfis e condições, basta estender o array multidimensional.

```php
//escolhendo computador conforme opções escolhidas
$computadores['diaadia']['economico']['cpu'] =  "Intel Celeron";
$computadores['diaadia']['economico']['rom'] =  "HDD 300GB";
$computadores['diaadia']['economico']['ram'] =  "2GB DDR3";

$computadores['diaadia']['normal']['cpu'] =  "Intel Core i3";
$computadores['diaadia']['normal']['rom'] =  "HDD 500GB";
$computadores['diaadia']['normal']['ram'] =  "4GB DDR3";

$computadores['trabalho']['economico']['cpu'] =  "Intel Core i3";
$computadores['trabalho']['economico']['rom'] =  "HDD 500GB";
$computadores['trabalho']['economico']['ram'] =  "4GB DDR3";

$computadores['trabalho']['normal']['cpu'] =  "Intel Core i5";
$computadores['trabalho']['normal']['rom'] =  "HDD 1TB";
$computadores['trabalho']['normal']['ram'] =  "8GB DDR3";
$computadores['trabalho']['normal']['video'] =  "2GB";

$computadores['edicao']['economico']['cpu'] =  "Intel Core i5";
$computadores['edicao']['economico']['rom'] =  "HDD 1TB";
$computadores['edicao']['economico']['ram'] =  "8GB DDR3";
$computadores['edicao']['economico']['video'] =  "2GB";

$computadores['edicao']['normal']['cpu'] =  "Intel Core i7";
$computadores['edicao']['normal']['rom'] =  "HDD 1TB";
$computadores['edicao']['normal']['ram'] =  "12GB DDR3";
$computadores['edicao']['normal']['video'] =  "4GB";


$cpu = $computadores[$perfil][$condicao]['cpu'];
$rom = $computadores[$perfil][$condicao]['ram'];
$ram = $computadores[$perfil][$condicao]['rom'];
if(isset($computadores[$perfil][$condicao]['video'])){
    $video = $computadores[$perfil][$condicao]['video'];
}
```

E na parte onde se exibe os dados:

```php
   echo "Processador: $cpu " . "<br>";
   echo "Armazenamento: $rom " . "<br>";
   echo "Memoria RAM: $ram "  . "<br>";
   if (isset($video)){
       echo "Placa de video dedicada: $video" . "<br>";
   }
```

Comment: Cara, deu um problema, ao pressionar o submit, dá erro 500

Comment: Nesse caso, você precisa ver os logs do Apache para identificar a causa.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use temporary expression in write context in /home/defaultwebsite/public/descubraseupc/form/index.php on line 33

Comment: Linha 33:     $computadores = ['diaadia']['economico']['cpu'] =  "Intel Celeron";

Comment: Tinha um erro nas atribuições, mas já corrigi a resposta. Você pode verificar, mas essencialmente, estava atribuindo errado

Comment: /home/defaultwebsite/public/descubraseupc/form/index.php on line 63 Notice: Undefined index: in /home/defaultwebsite/public/descubraseupc/form/index.php on line 63 Notice: Undefined variable: condicao in /home/defaultwebsite/public/descubraseupc/form/index.php on line 63 Notice: Undefined variable: perfil in /home/defaultwebsite/public/descubraseupc/form/index.php on line 64 Notice: Undefined variable: condicao in /home/defaultwebsite/public/descubraseupc/form/index.php on line 64

Comment: Linha 63: $ram = $computadores[$perfil][$condicao]['ram'];
Linha 64: if(isset($computadores[$perfil][$condicao]['video'])){

Comment: Lembrando que fiz uma alteração 62 e 63, porque estava ao contrario, onde era para ser "ram" tava "rom"

Comment: Isso é pq não veio o valor de $perfil e $condicao.Verifique se os dados estão vindo corretamente  do formulário.

Comment: Ok, resolvido. No entanto, um dos problemas iniciais continua. Ele não imprimi os resultados das variáveis, as outras strings sim, como "Processador: "

Comment: Ele está funcionando aqui: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce1554e10c213dea04c5268abcb7e091159d1528
Verifique atentamente o restante do seu código... E se ajudou, marque a resposta por favor.

Comment: Certo, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Disponha. Estamos aqui para ajudar.